# Getting Authenticated User in BPEL

Tags: web-services, authentication, soa, bpel

I'm using Oracle SOA and BPEL and I have setup an authentication requirement for calling a webservice which starts off a BPEL process.

What I'm trying to do is get the authenticated user inside the BPEL process.  I'd like to store the calling user in the Processes history in some way.  I've checked for any obvious ways to do this, so I'm wondering if there are any non-obvious ways to do this.

Comment: which authentication method are you using

Comment: oracle/wss10_saml_token_client_policy

Which is SAML as connected together by WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the OWSM policies. This can be done by right clicking on the Service from the composite.xml design view. Then select Configure WS Policies -> For Request.

[image: Service WS Policies]

For more information check out: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e10224/sca_policy.htm#CHDHAJIH